# ImageField Upload with Django

Tags: python, django, upload

I am trying to upload an image with django and so far i can't see the `upload_to` directory get created or any file source in the database field.

**My Model.**

```
class Person(models.Model):
  photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', null=True, blank=True)
```

**My View**

```
def create_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PartialPersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        addressForm = PartialAddressForm(request.POST)
```

When i upload and save, i dont get any sort of errors. Anyway i can debug this and find out if the photo field is set.

```
 <div class="photo-upload">{{ form.photo|attr:"onchange:readURL(this);" }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're doing something special with regard to media storage, you should set up [MEDIA_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) to the directory where you want the uploaded files to be saved.

When dealing with file-type fields, you will need to following instructions in the Django documentation for [FileField.storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage).

In your view, you will need to `save()` the uploaded form data.

```
def create_profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PartialPersonForm(request.POST, request.FILES,)
        addressForm = PartialAddressForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        addressForm.save()
```

Answer (score -2):

i believe you should create the upload_to directory yourself. Also make sure to set the appropriate permissions for the directory, otherwise it won't be able to write in it.

Comment: The directory doesn't have to be created, i did not have my MEDIA_ROOT PATH set in settings.py.